# javascript recursive iteration is returning entire parent div in the recursive iteration

Tags: javascript, html, recursion

I want to implement search functionality on my div whose html is as below :

```
<input type="search" id="mysearch" placeholder="Search here"     />
    <div  class="sken-cues-body" id="mydivbody">
         <div class="sken-cue-card" style="display: block;" >
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-title">Welcome to My Customer!</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    Want to help every sales agent like a <b>champion !</b>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a type="button" href="https://salesken.ai/sign-in.html" class="sken-button-theme">START HERE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex"  style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title">Talking Points</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text" id="11">
                    <ul >
                        <li>Greet the customer</li>
                        <li>Ask if it is a good time to talk</li>
                        <li>Be polite &amp; courteous on the call</li>
                        <li>Listen carefully</li>
                        <li>Thank the customer for their time</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex" style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title"></div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    <p>
                        Introduce yourself and why you are calling, ask if it is a good time to talk<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex" style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title">
                    <p>
                        <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13.3333px;">NPA Guidelines</span><br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    <p>
                        If the account has not been active for more than 90 days, it will be declared an NPA and that will lead to strident actions. Need to start&nbsp;paying the EMIs to avoid unnecessary legal hassles<br>
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

For implemention search functionality,i need to recursive iteration inside  div with ID mydivbody. Below is javascript function for recursive iteration in div with  ID mydivbody:

```
document.getElementById('mysearch').addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    var node = document.getElementById('mydivbody')
    allDescendants(node,this.value) 
});

function allDescendants (node) {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      var child = node.children[i];
      allDescendants(child);
         console.log(child)
      }

      //doSomethingToNode(child,search_value);
    }
```

But in this js function, i can see all child nodes where i am consoling the child along with entire parent div. for me node is getting duplicated. Please suggest how to fix this

Comment: You may filter the output. HTMLCollection is iterable so `[...(new Set([...children]))]` - and what you get is array without duplicates.

Comment: You mean it is printing the same node more than once?

Comment: Looks correct to me. I would swap the `console.log(child)` before the `allDescendants(child)` to make it more intuitive. To output the parent before its children.

Comment: Do you want to return a single result for the node that matches a given ID?

Comment: i want all the child nodes but not parent node. allDescendants return the parent itself. for e.g if html structure is Div1 >Div2>Div3. where Div3 is child of Div2 and Div2 is child of Div1. Then i want only Div 2 innertext and Div 3 innertext. Div 1 doesn't have any inner text. i want all innertext of entire tree structure which shouldn't be duplicate

Comment: @Zydnar Please give me some example of removing duplicate

Comment: Currently `allDescendants()` logs (it logs, it has no `return` so it returns `undefined`) all descendats of the passed element recursively. It does not contain the root element (=parent) nor duplicates. If you pass Div1 like you mention above it will log Div2>Div3, like you wanted. So, I do not compehend what changes you want to it.

Comment: Maybe `createTreeWalker(root,  4)` is what you are looking for? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recursive iteration of your function `allDescendants()` is actually correct and does not generate duplicates. If you `console.log()` an element it will also contain its children, which maybe makes you confused in it containing duplicates.

I expanded it with an actual `return` and a `Level` property to show you that the iteration is correct.

```js
function allDescendants(node, list, level){
    //REM: To actually return elements, thos get stored in a list
    var tList = list || [];
    var tLevel = ~~level;

    for(var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++){
        var child = node.children[i];

        //REM: Store children in the list
        tList.push({Level: tLevel, Element: child});

        //REM: Took the log before the call, makes it more intuitive
        //console.log(child);
        allDescendants(child, tList, tLevel+1)
    };

    return tList
};

var tResult = allDescendants(document.querySelector('#mydivbody'));

console.log(tResult);
```

```html
<input type="search" id="mysearch" placeholder="Search here"     />
    <div  class="sken-cues-body" id="mydivbody">
         <div class="sken-cue-card" style="display: block;" >
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-title">Welcome to My Customer!</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    Want to help every sales agent like a <b>champion !</b>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a type="button" href="https://salesken.ai/sign-in.html" class="sken-button-theme">START HERE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex"  style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title">Talking Points</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text" id="11">
                    <ul >
                        <li>Greet the customer</li>
                        <li>Ask if it is a good time to talk</li>
                        <li>Be polite &amp; courteous on the call</li>
                        <li>Listen carefully</li>
                        <li>Thank the customer for their time</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex" style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title"></div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    <p>
                        Introduce yourself and why you are calling, ask if it is a good time to talk<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex" style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title">
                    <p>
                        <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13.3333px;">NPA Guidelines</span><br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    <p>
                        If the account has not been active for more than 90 days, it will be declared an NPA and that will lead to strident actions. Need to start&nbsp;paying the EMIs to avoid unnecessary legal hassles<br>
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

If you just want the `textNodes` (innerText?) you could make use of [createTreeWalker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker).

```js
var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
  document.getElementById('mydivbody'),
  NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT
);

var nodeList = [];
var currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;

while(currentNode) {
  //nodeList.push(currentNode.wholeText);
  nodeList.push(currentNode.textContent);
  currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
};

console.log(nodeList);
```

```html
<input type="search" id="mysearch" placeholder="Search here"     />
    <div  class="sken-cues-body" id="mydivbody">
         <div class="sken-cue-card" style="display: block;" >
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-title">Welcome to My Customer!</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    Want to help every sales agent like a <b>champion !</b>
                </div>
                <div class="">
                    <a type="button" href="https://salesken.ai/sign-in.html" class="sken-button-theme">START HERE</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex"  style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title">Talking Points</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text" id="11">
                    <ul >
                        <li>Greet the customer</li>
                        <li>Ask if it is a good time to talk</li>
                        <li>Be polite &amp; courteous on the call</li>
                        <li>Listen carefully</li>
                        <li>Thank the customer for their time</li>
                    </ul>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
         <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex" style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title"></div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    <p>
                        Introduce yourself and why you are calling, ask if it is a good time to talk<br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sken-cue-card salesken-flex" style="display: block;">
            <div class="salesken-flex salesken-flex-column">
                <div class="sken-cue-time">2:16 pm</div>
                <div class="sken-cue-title">
                    <p>
                        <span style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 13.3333px;">NPA Guidelines</span><br>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="sken-cue-text">
                    <p>
                        If the account has not been active for more than 90 days, it will be declared an NPA and that will lead to strident actions. Need to start&nbsp;paying the EMIs to avoid unnecessary legal hassles<br>
                        <br>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
```